# why my function trigger by dynamodb created using AWS Amplify cant connect to external api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I tried everything, no error found from cloudwatch AWS, but the data never arrived in my rest API.

I tried to create trigger from dynamodb -> lambda -> typesense server

bellow the code

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const url ="https://search.ecogroovi.com/collections/test/documents"
  const apiKey = "xxxx"
  const user =[]

 event.Records.forEach( async (record)=>  {

   if (record.eventName=="INSERT"){
    const data = unmarshall(record.dynamodb.NewImage)
 
    const name =data.name
    const email =data.email
    const id =data.id
    const headers ={
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      "X-TYPESENSE-API-KEY":apiKey
    }
    const dataToSend ={name,email,id}
    
    console.log(dataToSend)
    axios.post(url,dataToSend,{headers}).then(response=>{
    console.log(response)
    return {body:JSON.stringify(response)}
    })

 

 
} else {
  return {message:"not insert"}
}

});

};
```

No data ever arrived from lambda to my rest api, no error  also, and the funny things, usually typesense will send response, also i got no response.

Im created my lambda using "amplify add function" with dynamodb trigger

Please help anyone, 7 hours just to create something should be simple.

Comment: What do CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function invocation show? Were there errors? Did the function time out? BTW you're not dealing with the async calls to axios.post correctly. You should map the records to an array of promises, one promise from each call to axios.post, and then your function should eventually return Promise.all(<array of promises>).

Comment: hai @jarmod , thanks for the answer, the cloudwatch said,the function run smoothly, no errors, okay i will try to use promise all

Comment: hi @jarmod it worked, thanks for your advice, even though the reponse from axios error , but the data went trough to my rest api

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to nice guy at the comment above,
i changed the code to like this...

```
     event.Records.forEach( async (record)=>  {

     if (record.eventName=="INSERT"){
     const data = unmarshall(record.dynamodb.NewImage)
 
     const name =data.name
     const email =data.email
     const id =data.id
     const headers ={
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      "X-TYPESENSE-API-KEY":apiKey
      }
      const dataToSend ={
      name:name,email:email,id:id}
    
      console.log(dataToSend)   
      user.push( axios.post(url,dataToSend,{headers})); 
      }

      });

      if (user.length==0){
      return Promise.resolve("no data")
       }

      return Promise.allSettled(user)
```

it worked now, eventhough there was an error for the response, but the data went trough